# How to make the path work to run tests outside of pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a test that passes with `pytest`. I also have an adjacent source that's a console app (not pytest) that exercises the same function that barfs with `ModuleNotFoundError` for the same function call.

**mylib/mylib.py:**

```
def adder(num1, num2):    
    return num1 + num2
```

**test/my_test.py:**

```
from mylib.mylib import adder


def test_adder():

    assert adder(2, 2) == 4
```

**test/mytest_outside_pytest.py:**

```
from mylib.mylib import adder

print(str(adder(2, 2)))
```

As I suggest `pytest` completes and indicates the test passed, but the following does not:

```
$ python3 test/mytest_outside_pytest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/mytest_outside_pytest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mylib.mylib import adder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib'
```

Nor does:

```
$ cd test/
$ python3 mytest_outside_pytest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytest_outside_pytest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mylib.mylib import adder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib'
```

I have empty `__init__.py` in both folders.  I don't know what pytest does to path loading that I can't replicate in my "main" console app.  Of course I don't really care about an adder lib, I'm just aiming at the smallest reproducible problem.

Comment: If you call `python3 -m pytest ...`, it adds the current path to the Python path, so the modules will be found. Just calling `python3 test/mytest.py` does not do this. As the import is relative to that root dir, the root dir must be in the Python path for the import to work.

Comment: I just tried `python3 -m pytest test/mytest_outside_pytest.py` and it says "collected 0 items" so not quite the outcome I was looking for .. "4" in stdout.

Comment: I've bolded the file names in the post. See mytest_outside_pytest.py - third code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pytest` has a quite complex mechanism to add some directories to the `PYTHONPATH` and allow tests to run automagically ([see the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/pythonpath.html))

When you do not use `pytest` you do not have this mechanism and you have to manage the `PYTHONPATH` by yourself.

---

**Why the PYTHONPATH is not correct in your case?**

When you run a module using `python path/to/module.py`, the interpreter adds the directory containing the  module (absolute path of `path/to` in this example) in the `PYTHONPATH`.

In your case, you run `python test/mytest_outside_pytest.py`and the interpreter adds the absolute path of `test` directory in the `PYTHONPATH`.

You can check it by adding `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the very beginning of your `mytest_outside_pytest.py` module to enter a debug session and run it. Then `import sys` and display the `sys.path` to see that `test` is the first directory in your `PYTHONPATH`.

You can also see that the root directory is not listed and thus the packages it contains cannot be imported.

---

**How to solve it?**

It can be done in multiple ways.

You can manually define the `PYTHONPATH` in your command:

```sh
PYTHONPATH=. python test/mytest_outside_pytest.py
```

or you can use `python -m ...` as suggested in comment (do not forget that in this case, you have to **specify a module, not a path**, and remember that it will work only from the directory containng the `mylib` and `test` packages):

```sh
python -m test.mytest_outside_pytest
```

In both cases, a debug session can show you that the root directory and the `test` directory are in the `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: `python3 -m test.mytest_outside_pytest` does indeed simply invoke the non-test in test/ and produce the desired output, "4" (without pythonpath changes)